# Angular caching on production env

Tags: angular, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps

I have a problem with caching angular app on production environment. I've uploaded a new version of the app but every first visit (when I type an address) results with an old view of the site. Hard refresh helps and after that a browser shows what it be shown... but with every new visit the problem occurs again. I'm using Angular 6 app and production configuration during build:

```
"production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "serviceWorker": true,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            },
            {
              "replace": "src/theme/theme-variables.scss",
              "with": "src/environments/scss/theme-variables.dev.scss"
            }
          ]
        }
```

With every update I see that index.html is new, because main.js hash is actual from the start. Maybe the problem is that I use PWA and a service worker doesn't register? (I don't have ssl configured yet)

Comment: If you don't have SSL configured, PWA won't install (unless you are testing with localhost). Check the console to see wether the app is installed or not. If it's not installed, then you might need to configure your webserver to disable caching for `index.html`

Comment: Yep, I tried to disable service worker but it didn't resolve the cache problem (or maybe did it wrong...)

Comment: Disable caching for index.html on your web server

Comment: <script src="/main.js?v=100"></script> you can change the version everytime you deploy into production. It is not going to affect anything.